# Cargar automaticamente un archivo html en otro (index.html) en un div del index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

necesito cargar una pagina en una pagina principal. Lo hice con .load("archivo.html") pero solo lo abre en firefox y si inspeccione trae un error de arbol desequilibrado de elementos, y chrome y explorer ni la abren me aparerce acceso denegado en la llamada del load()

Me pueden decir como remplazar el load() .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es"/ >
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/estilos.css"/>
  <title>Estación 2</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
     var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
     var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
     var f=new Date();
     document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
   $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(actualizar,500);
   }) 
   function actualizar(){
      $("#contenedor").load("write.html");
   }
  function actualizaReloj() {
    marcacion = new Date()
    Hora = marcacion.getHours()
    Minutos = marcacion.getMinutes()
    Segundos = marcacion.getSeconds()
    dn = "a.m"
    if (Hora > 12) {
    dn = "p.m"
    Hora = Hora - 12
  }
  if (Hora == 0)
  Hora = 12
  if (Hora <= 9) Hora = "0" + Hora
  if (Minutos <= 9) Minutos = "0" + Minutos
  if (Segundos <= 9) Segundos = "0" + Segundos 
  //Termina el Script del Reloj 
  var Script, Total
  Script =  Hora + ":" + Minutos + ":" + Segundos + " " + dn
  Total = Script
  document.getElementById('Reloj').innerHTML = Total
  setTimeout("actualizaReloj()", 1000)
  }
</script> 

</head>
<body onload="actualizaReloj()">
  <div>
    <p id="fecha"></p>
    <p id="Reloj"></p>
  </div>
    <div id="contenedor" ></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes. El acceso denegado pasa por lo general cuando tratas de hacer un `load` de un archivo que está en otro dominio. En este caso no podrás hacerlo desde el cliente por políticas de seguridad del navegador. ¿El fichero está en el mismo dominio?

Comment: si de hecho si esta alojado en el mismo

Comment: ¿Podrías actualizar tu pregunta y poner una imagen o el texto del error que te aparece en la consola?

Comment: Esto sale en firefox. Un árbol desequilibrado fue escrito usando document.write() causando que los datos de la red sean reparseados. Para más información https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar tu código por favor, Daniela?

Comment: ¿Si mueves el código javascript **antes del cierre del body** sigue pasando?

Comment: no creo que no funcionó

Comment: ¿ Ya validaste el html de write.html ? Seguramente esta mal formado, algun tag sin cerrar o un cierre sin tener un tag que lo abra, alguno signo `<` o `>` faltante

Comment: Primero, ¿Cuál es la finalidad de cargar la página dentro del div? Segundo, ¿Cuál es el problema central que quieres resolver?, tercero, ¿Qué contiene la página que quieres cargar?